# Display all field of one record in mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a table with many columns, one of that is lon/lat. After I draw all points on a map, I want to display all other columns contents if I right click on a specific point. (It looks like to change a row to a column). I need some ideas to do this.

Comment: If you click on a point in the map with the Info Tool you'll see the values for all columns in the Info Window. Would that work for you?

Comment: that is ok, but sorry I don't know how to get that tool

Comment: Thank Peter, I know how to use Info Tool recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Info Tool you can see the attribute data for a record in the Info window.

In the Info window the attributes are shown in a "Column" style in contrast to the Browser window that shows each record in a separate row.

You can use the Info Tool in map windows as well as Browser windows

[image: Viewing attributes in a browser versus the Info window]